# Convert xap to exe

Tags: silverlight, exe, xap

Can anybody suggest a tool to convert Silverlight xap files to Windows executables? I googled and got this [this link](http://www.google.mu/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://www.csscript.net/help/wpf.html&ei=sSR9UNmnDI2rrAex8ICwAg&usg=AFQjCNHaEz5s2ciDAics9JIKVQveQ7neBw) but it does not work.

Edit: The Silverlight application has been compiled without the out-of-browser switch and I want to know if there is a solution which does not require me to open the project and recompile with out-of browser mode on.

Comment: what about enabling out of browser?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the out of browser mode. But, given a xap file, I want to know if there is another method without recompiling.

Comment: You can try Wix. But wix has a high learning curve

Comment: Good idea ! Why didn't I do that before. Its just a compressed file.It mustn't be hard. Thank you for giving this idea for us. I'm learning much things from questions.

Answer (score 1):

A XAP file is just a Zip file that has a different extension. You can easily use libraries like SharpLib or DotNetZip to extract the contents of it. You can also manualy change the extension of a .xap file to .zip and then extract it in a folder. When extracted, you would get all the assemblies that were bundled as part of the .xap file.

Everything is clearly explained in the following link,

[Extracting Assemblies from a XAP File](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/joydip/archive/2012/03/14/Extracting-Assemblies-from-a-XAP-File.aspx)

Comment: While posting links is great, please also post a brief summary of the link content too - just for in case the link becomes inaccessible in the future.

Comment: link only answers are not welcome on SO. please add some more detail to your answer.

Comment: I understand that the xap file is a container. But I want some kind of wrapper to convert it to a standalone executable. One method is to use Visual Studio and recompile the project as exe. But I want to know if there is another method without recompiling.

Answer (score 1):

This link might be of interest:

http://www.amazedsaint.com/2010/05/how-to-create-offline-installer-no.html

It describes creating an installer that installs silverlight on machines where it is not present, as well as an Out-of-browser silverlight application and start menu links. You can use this installer on machines with no internet connection and no .net runtime installed. So it offers most of the practical benefits of converting it to an exe. I followed that procedure before and found it good.

Comment: I find that it requires recompiling the project to work in out-of-browser mode and I want to solution that does not require recompilation.